# "??" operator in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have following code:

```
const helperText = fieldError ?? !salesforceLink ? t('editEstimate.reviewInformation.mandatoryFieldsError') : '';
```

Can anybody exmplain me or event send a link what `??` is?

Comment: https://indepth.dev/double-question-marks-typescript-3-7-nullish-coalescing/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described [in the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing):

The nullish coalescing operator is another upcoming ECMAScript feature that goes hand-in-hand with optional chaining, and which our team has been involved with championing in TC39.

You can think of this feature - the ?? operator - as a way to “fall back” to a default value when dealing with null or undefined. When we write code like

```
let x = foo ?? bar();
```

this is a new way to say that the value foo will be used when it’s “present”; but when it’s null or undefined, calculate bar() in its place.

Again, the above code is equivalent to the following.

```
let x = (foo !== null && foo !== undefined) ?
    foo :
    bar();
```

The ?? operator can replace uses of || when trying to use a default value. For example, the following code snippet tries to fetch the volume that was last saved in localStorage (if it ever was); however, it has a bug because it uses ||.

```
function initializeAudio() {
    let volume = localStorage.volume || 0.5

    // ...
}
```

When localStorage.volume is set to 0, the page will set the volume to 0.5 which is unintended. ?? avoids some unintended behavior from 0, NaN and "" being treated as falsy values.

Answer (score 0):

[nullish coalescing operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing)

> The nullish coalescing operator is another upcoming ECMAScript feature that goes hand-in-hand with optional chaining, and which our team has been involved with championing in TC39.

> You can think of this feature - the ?? operator - as a way to “fall back” to a default value when dealing with null or undefined. When we write code like

```
let x = foo ?? bar();
```

> this is a new way to say that the value foo will be used when it’s “present”; but when it’s null or undefined, calculate bar() in its place.

> Again, the above code is equivalent to the following.

```
let x = (foo !== null && foo !== undefined) ?
foo :
bar();
```